# What is the difference between view and render?

Tags: codeigniter

What is the difference between view and render in codeigniter?

Comment: Where do you find the 'render' part? As far as I know, there's no rendering part of CI?

Answer (score 6):

some template libraries use `$this->template->render();` to output the rendered content based on your template. (you must have the template library installed obviously)

```
function index()
{
    $this->template->set_template('main_template');
    $data['content'] = 'hello this is my content';
    $this->template->write_view('content', $data);    
    $this->template->render();
}
```

is in effect the same as

```
function index()
{
    $data['content'] = 'hello this is my content';
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/content', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

template libraries save the need to load each partial view every time.

Answer (score 0):

Render is not an out-of-the-box Codeigniter function for loading view files. Render is primarily used by Codeigniter template libraries like [Collin William's Template Library](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/?v14) or [Phil Sturgeon's Template Library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template).

The following two methods for view files are supported by Codeigniter right in the core code without using third party libraries or core extensions.

### $this->load->view()

The standard and most used way of loading a view file. Does not support any fancy syntax except [alternative control syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) structured PHP code or standard PHP code.

### $this->parser->parse()

Using the in-built Codeigniter parser which supports a Smarty like syntax only not as powerful. Also allows you to code view files using standard PHP and HTML as well.