# Codigniter: I don't want to load the header and footer part of my template on the login page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**This is my login controller**

in my login page i haven't need to loaded header and footer part

```
public function login()
{
    $head = array();
    $data = array();
    $head['title'] = lang('user_login');
    $head['description'] = lang('user_login');
    $head['keywords'] = str_replace(" ", ",", $head['title']);

    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    $referrer = $this->agent->referrer();
    $this->session->set_userdata('login_redirection_page',$referrer);
    $this->render('login', $head, $data);
}
```

Comment: Where are you loading header and footer in `view`?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sr2lg3
please see this i am highlighted the header and footer file

Comment: @sauhardnc can you see?

Comment: I meant where you add them in your view? Like `$this->load->view('header');`

Comment: I can't found this line also. i am not developed this site @sauhardnc

Comment: ok, then show me login.php file

Comment: please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760194/2275490

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below steps.

1. Go to render function definition and verify how they are loading the header and footer files, if code exists to skip header and footer files(by passing some parameters as false or etc), proceed accordingly.
2. If code doesn't exists to do so write logic to skip header and footer files by passing some parameters.
3. Otherwise comment `$this->render('login', $head, $data);` code and add below code.

   $this->load->view('login', $data);